# Make jquery tabs remember selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tabLink").each(function(){
      $(this).click(function(){
        tabeId = $(this).attr('id');
        $(".tabLink").removeClass("activeLink");
        $(this).addClass("activeLink");
        $(".tabcontent").addClass("hide");
        $("#"+tabeId+"-1").removeClass("hide")   
        return false;     
      });
    });  
  });
</script>
```

and this HTML:

```
<div class="tab-box"> 
<a href="javascript:;" class="tabLink activeLink" id="companyinfo">Company</a> 
<a href="javascript:;" class="tabLink" id="contacts">Contacts</a>
</div>

<div class="tabcontent" id="companyinfo-1">
content 1 here
</div>

<div class="tabcontent" id="contacts-1">
content 2 here
</div>
```

if the page is refreshed, the first tab is selected again. how can i make it remember my selection if the page is refreshed?

Comment: you can set your current tab value in hidden field variable and check it in document.ready

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the index of the clicked tab in `localStorage`.

```
 // on click, save it in localStorage.selectedTab
localStorage.selectedTab = $(this).index() + 1;

// on document ready, after click handler was added search for it
if (localStorage.selectedTab) {
  $(".tabLink:eq(" + (localStorage.selectedTab - 1) + ")").click();
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gtXbm/1/)

Another solution would be using cookies, but I find localStorage easier.

---

Also, you can use the `active` field in the `tabs` API using, like [Atakan Aral](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4107136/atakan-aral) said:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    activate: function( event, ui ) {
        localStorage.selectedTab = ui.newTab.index() + 1;
    },
    active: localStorage.selectedTab ? localStorage.selectedTab - 1 : 0
});
```

Comment: ok cool - i have many pages with the tabs on so i have added this code into a file called jquery-tabs.php and i then include this file on all my other pages using php include 'jauery-tabs.php'; - should this still work?

Comment: @charlie I guess you must reserve one key from `localStorage` for each page that have tabs... For example `localStorage["selectedTab" + location.pathname` and then you check it `if (localStorage["selectedTab" + location.pathname]) {...}`.

Answer (score 3):

A more compact jQuery UI version of ionică-bizău's answer:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    activate: function( event, ui ) {
        localStorage.selectedTab = ui.newTab.index() + 1;
    },
    active: localStorage.selectedTab ? localStorage.selectedTab - 1 : 0
});
```