# Local storage remember clicked tab class

Tags: html, jquery, local-storage

Based on this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18760763/make-jquery-tabs-remember-selection), I'm trying to save the clicked tab "a" element in local storage, and add the class "active" to its parent, the "li" element. But so far no success and I'm sure the problem is in the last part of the jquery code.

```
<ul class="nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="javascript:;" class="tab-link" id="logo-tab">Logo Tab</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="tab-link" id="header-tab">Header Tab</a></li> 
    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="tab-link" id="footer-tab">Footer Tab</a></li> 
</ul>

<div id="logo-tab-1" class="tab-content active">
logo tab content demo
</div>

<div id="header-tab-1" class="tab-content">
header tab content demo
</div>

<div id="footer-tab-1" class="tab-content">
footer tab content demo
</div>
```

CSS

```
.tab-content{
  display:none;
}

.tab-content.active{
  display:block;
}
```

jquery

```
$(".tab-link").each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
          localStorage.selectedTab = $(this).index() + 1;
          tabId = $(this).attr('id');
          $(".tab-link").parent('li').removeClass("active");
          $(this).parent('li').addClass("active");
            //   tab content
          $(".tab-content").removeClass("active");
          $("#"+tabId+"-1").addClass("active"); 
          return false;     
        });
      });  
        
      // search for local storage
      if (localStorage.selectedTab) {
        $(".tab-link:eq(" + (localStorage.selectedTab - 1) + ")").click().parent('li').addClass("active");
      }
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/npz0s5my/3/) code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm is correct! The only problem is that `$(this).index()` doesn't return the wanted value.

You need to get the index from your loop `.each(function(index)`, and then use it `localStorage.selectedTab = index + 1`.

```
$(".tab-link").each(function(index) {
  $(this).click(function() {
    localStorage.selectedTab = index + 1;
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that `localStorage.selectedTab` returns a string instead of an integer value.

so instead of `localStorage.selectedTab - 1` which might produce 11 in case localStorage would be 1, you can write `parseInt(localStorage.selectedTab) - 1`.

Example:

```
> localStorage.test = 1
< 1
> localStorage.test + 1
< "11"
```

Comment: I tried both of your examples and no success: https://jsfiddle.net/sz3jecky/ and https://jsfiddle.net/npz0s5my/4/